# Have an issue with training a question answering model using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, tf.keras

I am trying to create a question answering model, where I have taken a dataset of standardnlp/coqa. I have iterated through the dataset and created two lists named input_texts which has a strings of questions and target_texts, which contains strings of answers.

```
input_texts = [entry['input'] for entry in dialog[:85]]
target_texts = [entry['output'] for entry in dialog[:85]]
```

So, the first row or we can say input_text[0] has the question and target_text[0] has its answer. Likewise there is many questions and answers.
So I used the below code to train a model, which will create answers.

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(input_texts + target_texts)
print(tokenizer.word_index)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
input_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(input_texts)
target_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(target_texts)
max_seq_length = max(len(seq) for seq in input_sequences + target_sequences)
input_sequences = pad_sequences(input_sequences, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='post')
target_sequences = pad_sequences(target_sequences, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='post')
embedding_dim = 128
units = 256

encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
encoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_embedding)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
decoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_embedding, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
# Define the model
model = tf.keras.models.Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')

# Train the model
model.fit([input_sequences, target_sequences], target_sequences, batch_size=64, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)
```

After the training is done, while I am trying to predict a new answer using the below code.

```
input_text = "This is a new sentence"
input_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([input_text])
input_sequence = pad_sequences(input_sequence, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='post')
predicted_text = ""
temp = np.array([len(predicted_text)]).reshape(-1, 1)
prediction = model.predict([input_sequence, temp])
print(type(prediction))
print(prediction)
```

The output is like this

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[[1.22179881e-01 1.13135399e-02 2.29560435e-04 7.00173132e-07
   7.06581259e-03 4.08492895e-04 2.04439188e-04 1.95089683e-07
   7.77692010e-04 3.04014375e-03 3.92067705e-07 1.75819430e-03
   1.36362482e-03 1.83400698e-02 3.99890553e-07 3.23555355e-07

    . . . .    

   4.33137558e-07 3.96126751e-07 3.73236958e-07 5.68119503e-07
   3.85419099e-07 3.75457518e-07 3.54693100e-07 2.95670617e-07
   2.87792005e-07 2.88322184e-07 9.58226906e-07 4.79546600e-07
   8.11190148e-07 5.48521825e-07 2.83977812e-07]]]
```

So my doubt is , how to convert this array back to the text format.

I have tried many methods, but not working. Below is the code I used to convert it.

```
predicted_index = np.argmax(prediction[0, -1, :])
print(predicted_index)
for timestep in predicted_index[0]:
    # Check if the index exists in the tokenizer's index_word dictionary
    if timestep != 0 and timestep in tokenizer.index_word:
        # Convert the index back to a word
        predicted_word = tokenizer.index_word[timestep]
        
        # Append the word to the predicted text
        predicted_text += predicted_word + ' '

    # Check for end-of-sequence token

    # Update decoder input for the next prediction
temp = np.array([len(predicted_text)]).reshape(-1, 1)

print("Predicted Text:", predicted_text)
```